# Not able fetch and display particular data - react native

Tags: json, react-native, fetch-api

```
      import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
  AppRegistry,
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  View,
  Navigator,
  TouchableOpacity,
  Image,
  TextInput,                                            
  TouchableHighlight,                                            
  Alert
} from 'react-native';

import Button from 'react-native-button'
import {Actions} from 'react-native-router-flux'
import Home from './Home'

export class Weight extends Component{
    constructor(props) {
  super(props);

  this.state = {
    data: '',
    data1:'',
    textinput:'',
    entryDate: '',
    systol:''
  }

  componentDidMount(){
    this._onPressButtonGET();
  } 
 _onPressButtonPOST(){
            fetch("url", {
                method: "POST",
                 headers: {
                     'Accept': 'application/json',
                     'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                 },
                body: JSON.stringify({
                    "entryDate":"3/2/2017 2:00 AM",
                    "systol": "120",
                    "mobileType":"ANDROID",
                    "userName":"menutest"

                })})
            .then((response) => response.json())
            .then((responseData) => {
                Alert.alert(
                    "Blood pressure data",
                    "Blood pressure data - " + JSON.stringify(responseData)
                )
            })
            .done();
        }

        _onPressButtonGET ()  {
            fetch("url", {
                method: "POST",
                 headers: {
                     'Accept': 'application/json',
                     'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                 },
                body: JSON.stringify({"mobileType":"ANDROID","userName":"menutest"})})
            .then((response) => response.json())
            .then((responseData) => {
                    this.setState({ data: JSON.stringify(responseData) })
                })

            .done();
        }
    render(){
            return(
                <View>
                    <TouchableHighlight onPress={this._onPressButtonPOST}>
                        <Text>Add</Text> 
                    </TouchableHighlight>


                     <TouchableHighlight onPress={this._onPressButtonGET.bind(this)}>
                        <Text>show</Text>
                       </TouchableHighlight>

                      <Text>{this.state.responseData.entryDate}</Text>
                      <Text>{this.state.responseData.systol}</Text>
                       <Text>hello{this.state.data}</Text> 

                </View>
            );
        }
    }

    module.exports = Weight;
```

I want to display only systol and entryDate on the screen, but my above code is displaying all the data from web services, How can i edit my code that i want to display only those things? i tried with    this.setState({ data: responseData.entryDate }) but this is not working [need help](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1034126/amb).
and how to use for loop in _onPressButtonGET() to display all entry dates and systol.

Answer (score 1):

If response data is an object 
instead of

`this.setState({ data: JSON.stringify(responseData) })`

use

**`this.setState({ entryDate: responseData.entryDate, systol: responseData.systol })`**

and then in the render use 
**`{this.state.entryDate}` and `{this.state.systol}`**

First make sure you have a clean code in the constructor (add *}* after setting the state), then make sure you fetch data from the correct url and not just a string, then make sure you receive the exact data that you need and that is a object, then set the info you need on state as I described above, then use it in the render function.

Comment: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'this.state.responsedata.entryData') this is error i am getting.

Comment: I edited my answer! Make sure you store and update on state only what you need and the keys from the state object are matching the keys used in render.

Comment: add some console.logs before setting the state like this: console.log(typeof responseData) console.log(Object.keys(responseData)) before this.setState({ entryDate: responseData.entryDate, systol: responseData.systol })

Comment: how can i use for loop here? actually i have many entryDate and systol?

Comment: console.log() is not making any difference

Comment: if entryData looks like this [{id: 1, name: 'aa'},{id: 2, name: 'bb'}] then in the render use something like this: 
                {this.state.entryData.map(function (item) {
                    return ([
                        <Text>{item.name}</Text>
                     ]);
                })} and that will display rows of Text with names from entryData

Comment: If the code still doesn't work tell me what is the result of console.logs(typeof response and the keys)

Comment: i didnot get what is entryData. i have entryDate, that is also a attribute.

Comment: I used entryData example for the case the information is an array and you need to display multiple lines. Did the solution work to display entryDate?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/137658/discussion-between-florin-dobre-and-prasanna).